# What's the best way to find out the installed version of the iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, macos

What is the easiest way of finding out what version of the iPhone SDK is installed on my OS X?

When you log into the Apple's iPhone Developer Center, you can see the build number of the current available version of the SDK, but you have to remember if you have already downloaded that version or not.

What is the easiest way of staying current?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a cross post from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480184/how-do-i-determine-which-iphone-sdk-i-have/).

> The best place to check which version of the iPhone SDK you have installed is to use System Profiler.
>
> Apple Menu > About this Mac > More Info... > Software > Developer
>
> Once there, you'll see version and build numbers for all of the major components of the Developer Tools. The top level version and build number corresponds to the name of the disk image you downloaded from Apple.
>
> This works in Snow Leopard, but apparently not in Leopard. I don't know of a singularly useful equivalent in Leopard. Consider upgrading :)

Comment: Thanks! I marked this as accepted considering Snow Leopard will be the most common platform for Mac developers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you get the version number for any SDK from the CoreServices/SystemVersion plist file:

*$Developer*/Platforms/*$Platform*.platform/Developer/SDKs/*$SDK*.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist.

You should see an entry for the ProductBuildVersion.

Comment: This number doesn't help when deciding to grab the latest dmg from developer.apple.com. System Profiler > Software > Developer in Snow Leopard gives you all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at the file named "About iPhone SDK.pdf" under /Developer ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After your suggestion I read that document and, although it talks about the version of XCode included in the SDK (in this case the 3.1), there is no information on what SDK build number is installed.

Comment: In Snow Leopard, try System Profiler > Software > Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Use xcrun.

Examples:

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk

$  xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version
11.0

$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-build-version
15A372
```

Check `xcrun --help` for other options you might be interested in.